# IOS alert message

Tags: iphone

I have a small problem in a theater website I have developed. The whole site works just fine up until a booking is made on an iphone - when the submission form is sent a message appears: "value must be less or equal to 0" just below the number input element. Maybe the answers there, just glaring up at my face, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. Can anyone help me please on this issue?

Below is the input field in question:

```html
<input id="box1" class="number-input inum tgv-index" min="0" name="nietleden" type="number" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*"/>
```

Comment: Can you share the log of values that is retrieved from the textfield on clieck of submit?

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your answer. Today I went to the test platform, intent on retrieving the log files, and tried again to submit the form again and what do you know, this time it worked. Seems the code I implemented yesterday evening did the trick. I thought perhaps if I could omit the number input field, substitute it with a text field instead. Why the iPhone has a problem with the number input field is however not clear to me.

Comment: Same I was hoping to figure. But next time. I am glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to solve the problem for me. I placed the following code in the header.php. To determine if an iOS system is being used, then it will change the the number input element attribute to a text input attribute.

```js
   function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
    
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;      
    if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
     setTimeout(function() {
      showMessage('init');
      document.querySelector('#box1').setAttribute('type', 'text');
      document.querySelector('#box2').setAttribute('type', 'text');
      document.querySelector('#box3').setAttribute('type', 'text');     
     }, 2000);
    }
   }
   getMobileOperatingSystem();
```